# Can I inline drawings in a caption

Tags: captions, diagrams

I am attempting to include a simple drawing in the caption of a figure. The drawing is simply a line which I am using to include a sort of legend in the caption.

I have tried to achieve this both by using a `picture` environment and an inline `\tikz` command, but neither works. It seems that `\caption` does not tolerate this kind of content? I have also foolishly attempted to mend this by `\protect`'ing the drawing, but that does not seem to help.

The reason I have not given up yet is that my attempts actually seem to produce the desired drawing inside the caption, but they throw errors like:

```
ERROR: Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
```

So is there a way to fix what I am attempting here?

UPDATE:

@pluton's suggestion below seems to work. In addition, I would like if it could work with a LaTeX `picture` as well since I would like to avoid loading TiKZ in the current project. Specifically, I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{Test \protect{\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
    \begin{picture}(5,3)
      \put(0,1){\line(5,0){5}}
    \end{picture}}}
 \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which gives me the above error.

The (erroneous) output, however, seems to look fine:

[image: Output showing the resulting caption.]

Comment: I think you should show us what you have tried already, otherwise it's wildly guessing around

Comment: Doesn't that sort of information belong on the figure it self?

Comment: With TikZ consider the `\protect` command as follows: `\caption{\protect\tikz{\protect\fill[white] (0,-0.3em) rectangle (1.8em,0.3em);\protect\draw[#1] (0,0) -- (1.8em,0);})}`. I do not know why it works and other combinations fail.

Comment: @daleif you might indeed argue that it belongs in the figure itself, but I find that the solution I am trying to achieve might be nicer since it avoids cluttering the figure with a legend box.

Comment: @pluton Your example works for me. I had not considered `\protect`'ing the individual drawing commands inside `\tikz`.

Comment: @ThomasArildsen, then do you mind posting an image showing the end result?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have added an example now.

Comment: @pluton care to make it an answer?

Comment: the output _in the figure_ is not generating the error message, the problem is the definitions are expanding (incorrectly) while writing to the `lof` file so if you use `\listoffigures` you will find the file is corrupt and will not read back in correctly.

Comment: Also will this kind of information actually make any sense being listed in the LOF?

Answer (score 4):

`\protect` applies to single tokens, never apply it to `{`

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\zzz{{\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}%
    \begin{picture}(5,3)
      \put(0,1){\line(5,0){5}}
    \end{picture}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{Test \protect\zzz}
 \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on David Carlisle's answer, one possible solution with `Tikz` is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,tikz]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\strokeA{[\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.base)]{\draw[red,line width=2pt] (0,3pt) -- (1.8em,3pt);}]}
\newcommand\strokeB{[\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.base)]{\draw[blue,line width=2pt] (0,3pt) -- (1.8em,3pt);}]}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{Title: legend A \protect\strokeA{} and legend B \protect\strokeB}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]